# What's the "official" name of the trust selling block in e-commerce?

Tags: terminology

We are using a trust selling block in our online store like many web sites have,  but we don't know its real name. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We are using a trust selling block in our online store like many web sites have, but we don't know its real name.

It's called a "Benefit Statement", in [point form](https://www.copyblogger.com/little-known-ways-to-write-fascinating-bullet-points/) to create a [spotlight](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spotlight) or [highlight](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highlight), each individual one is a bullet point or [selling point](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/selling%20point). It provides the top reasons why someone might choose you over others, it's what you [lead](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead) with, your [opening](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open).

Examples supporting that definition:

- [How to Write an Effective Benefit Statement](https://pixelmark.net/how-to-write-an-effective-benefit-statement/)
- [Learn How Benefit Statements Affect Sales](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/the-benefits-of-benefits-statements-2917228)
- [A Framework for Writing Project Benefit Statements](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/framework-writing-project-benefit-statements-philip-meitiner)
- [Using Benefit Statements](https://www.nasp.com/article/6B76BDE7-3415/using-benefits-statements.html)