# Banner strip of power statements on a landing page. Is there a name for this feature?

Tags: website-design

I have been given a brief to design a 'banner strip' of power statements on a landing page.
I am looking for inspiration but I cant find the best term to use to find what I am looking for.
I have an example below of what my client is looking for but struggle to find any other examples. Could anyone put me in the right direction?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the "official" name of the trust selling block in e-commerce?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125188/whats-the-official-name-of-the-trust-selling-block-in-e-commerce)

Comment: Where does this banner strip appear in the landing page? A lot of UI components are named based on a combination of how they appear on the interface and what content/interactions are contained within.